# I don't get invited to many parties. what is the tense?

Tags: tense

What is the tense of the following sentence?

> I **don't get invited** to  <strike>the party</strike> many parties.

**Update:**

**Note:** I heard the above statement from British native speaker.

As examples of same form structure:

> “None of those things happened. So **I don’t get caught up** in that. We don’t like talking about expectation. From our end I think all the excitement is coming from the outside.” [The Daily Telegraph](http://www.dailytelegraph.com.au/sport/nrl/teams/panthers/penrith-panthers-dont-believe-hype-around-their-nrl-premiership-chances-says-coach-anthony-griffin/news-story/9984664d3f6682daa20a06363883f663)
>
> "**I don’t get looked** at as much as I used to because I was putting it out there with the cropped tops, cleavage everywhere and the peacock walk ..." [Mirror](http://www.mirror.co.uk/3am/celebrity-news/anastacia-how-didnt-nerves-strictly-9912054)

Why do they use *don't* with *past form*?

Shouldn't they say?

> I *didn't* get *invite* to  <strike>the party</strike> many parties.

Comment: That seems a rather unlikely sentence. Are you sure you don't mean _didn't_ or _won't_ get invited ..."?

Comment: To add to BillJ's comment, you might refer to the more general case with, "I don't get invited to parties."

Comment: @fixer1234 may you are right, maybe I misheard the guy

Comment: Your edit adds an interesting wrinkle.  The two examples are correct and those phrases refer to the present: "I do not get caught up in that", and "I do not get looked at".  I think the problem with the original phrase might be a singular/plural issue, although I'm having trouble putting my finger on the precise rule.  "I do not get invited" seems like it should refer to something plural, so "the party" (singular) doesn't match.  (cont'd)

Comment: I think the difference with the other two is that the other parts of the sentence are connected with "so" or "because", allowing the rest to be different in tense, quantity, etc.  In the original sentence, "to the party" directly describes the first part.  I'd post this as an answer, but not being able to cite the rule would leave this lacking.

Comment: The difference between the original sentence and the additional ones is that, for the additional ones, present simple is used to denote a regular occurence, in the same way as "I don't smoke" relates to a habitual activity- or rather its absence. The original sentence would only work if it related to repeatedly not being invited to parties, and for that "party" would have to be plural: "I don't get invited to parties".

Comment: If I didn't get invited to many parties, I'd be **very** tense.

Answer (score 2):

It's present tense, used to make a definite event more immediate rather than putting it in the obvious past.

Some stories are told in present tense so they sound like they're being narrated almost as they happen, which tends to make them more exciting or visceral, and this could fit in smoothly into such a story. To give a terrible, melodramatic example:

> Janey says she'll invite me for sure, just wait for the call. Two days later, I'm waiting by the phone.
>
> *I don't get invited to the party.*
>
> I spend two hours trying to make excuses for why she's calling me late and three hours crying.

Even though the narration is telling of events that happened, it's telling of them as though at the same time as they happened.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of that angle if I hadn't seen your example.  Very good.